# How do I see the SQL commands issued against ASPNETDB and watch the dataflow?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication

Just about everything I've seen relating to ASP.Net's Login control treats it like a black box. I'm interested in seeing the SQL commands issued against ASPNETDB and watching the dataflow.

For example, the Login control uses ASPNETDB and stored procedure `dbo.aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByName`.  I'm not clear on how to call the procedure because it expects `@PageIndex` and `@PageSize` parameters (`@ApplicationName` and `@UserNameToMatch` make sense to me). I would like to read about the procedure or trace it.

Would anyone know of good reading on the topic, or suggest a path to explore the control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [SQL Server Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx).  The Graphical User Interface for SQL Traces is [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).  This only ships with certain versions of SQL Server (for instance, if you have SQL Server Express Edition then you will not have SQL Server Profiler, but you will still be able to utilize the Trace stored procedures and database objects).

Using Profiler (or the Trace db objects), you'll be able to filter out certain events and data depending on what you are specifically looking to capture.  This will give you all the information you'll need to find out the data being transmitted to and from the server -> client application (or in this case, the ASP.NET application).

The events and data that a Trace puts forth can be *extremely* daunting, especially if you are new to this (which it sounds like you are) and there are a lot of hits to the database.  Learn about the [Profiler Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190176.aspx) you can utilize, and the individual [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175481.aspx) you can analyze.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to SQL Server, then fire up the profiler and you can see in real-time the sql statements executed against the db.

Just for good measure a brief step by step guide for starting up profiler.

[Starting up SQL profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx)

If your using SQL express you may not have profiler, however here's an open source alternative (note. I've never used it)

[free profiler](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/)

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up to use SQL Server (using aspnet_regsql.exe), you can see the stored procedures it uses.

Comment: "you can see the stored procedures it calls" - Right. I want to read an essay on the operations and/or trace the calls.